# Add count to each row extracted from table

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have  a table like below:

```
name age dept
A   22  IT
B   23  CS
C   24  FI
```

Below is my table structure I have defined in class.

```
@Table(name = "employee")
@Entity
@IdClass(Emp_uniqueCount.class)
public class Emp_uniqueCount implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="name")
    String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name="age")
    String age;

    @Id
    @Column(name="dept")
    String dept;

    }
```

Interface:

```
@Component
public interface Employeee_details_Repositry extends Repository<emp_uniqueCount, Integer> {
    List<emp_uniqueCount> findAll();

}
```

And my main rest class;

```
@Autowired
    Employeee_details_Repositry employeeedetailsRepositry;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pqr", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<emp_uniqueCount> employeeDetails() {
        List<emp_uniqueCount> empList = employeeedetailsRepositry.findAll();

        return empList ;

    }
```

My output give like below and this is perfect:

```
{

    "name": "A",
    "age": "22",
    "dept": "IT",
 }
```

How can I add a count=1 for each record .like below ..

```
{

    "name": "A",
    "age": "22",
    "dept": "IT",
    "count":1
 }
```

Comment: is there any circumstance in which count would not be 1?

Comment: @Nick..In my case I want to keep only 1..This is a specific case

Answer (score 0):

As you depicted, `count` is not a persistent attribute so you have to compute it. So you have to modify `emp_uniqueCount` class to add a new transient attribute called count:

```
transient Integer count;
```

Sure you can post-process `serverNameList` once you have retrieved from repository, to fill count attribute, as you want.

By the way, it is bad practice to name java classes using first lowercase.

Comment: If I change your question code, any readers won't understand your question, I think it is not appropriate. My suggestion is very straightforward. Add the attribute, and then, after retrieving the List, do a for each bucle to fill count attribute as you want.

Comment: Yoo..Got it ..Thanks...did it